# How do I access POST variables in my controller?

Tags: java, post, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am making the following AJAX request:

```
$.post('/route', {
    arg1 : 'foo',
    arg2 : 'bar'
});
```

Through the route:

```
POST   /route    controllers.Test.readPost()
```

How do I access these POST variables in the method of my controller?

```
public static Result readPost() {
    return TODO; // read post variables
}
```

I cannot find a simple way of doing this in the documentation. It only states how to get values from JSON requests.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `DynamicForm`

```
public static Result getValues(){
    DynamicForm requestData = form().bindFromRequest();

    String name = requestData.get("name");
    String desg = requestData.get("desg");
    // etc

    return ok("You sent: " + name + ", " + desg);
}
```

There is also other possibility to construct AJAX query and pass arguments via `javascriptRoutes`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11133586/1066240

Of course it will pass the params via URL so it's not suitable for every value, but in many places it will be goot enough for sending POST requests with AJAX. Of course `javascriptRoutes` create the request with type set in `routes` file.

*BTW: it was better if you wrote which version you are using.*

Comment: Worked like a charm. Is this documented?

Comment: DynamicForm is documented in the API http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.1/java/index.html?play/data/package-summary.html , as far as I know, there's no official doc for javascriptRoutes yet

Answer (score -2):

you can use GET with an ajaxRequest. more information can be found here http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/ajaxgetpost.shtml

```
var mygetrequest=new ajaxRequest()
mygetrequest.onreadystatechange=function(){
 if (mygetrequest.readyState==4){
  if (mygetrequest.status==200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1){
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=mygetrequest.responseText
  }
  else{
   alert("An error has occured making the request")
  }
 }
}
var namevalue=encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("name").value)
var agevalue=encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("age").value)
mygetrequest.open("GET", "basicform.php?name="+namevalue+"&age="+agevalue, true)
mygetrequest.send(null)
```

Comment: This is completely unrelated to the question. I'm asking about the `play framework`, and POST not GET.