# Error while loading file in jquery forntier calendar

Tags: java, jquery, jquery-plugins, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am using play 2.0.2. and implemented jquery calendar plugin in play. To load events to calendar i need to load a file. But when i am doing from play i am getting loading error.

the code written is

```
var url1= '@routes.Assets.at("Calender.ics")';
jfcalplugin.loadICalSource("#mycal",url1,"html");
```

Could any one suggest for this problem? (If the question is not clear please let me know.)

Comment: Check my edited answer please. There is advice how to debug JS in the browser, most probably you have some problem on JavaScript level.

Comment: Thanks for advice... i will recheck my JS code :)

Comment: And set your name please, it's easier to remember to who I'm writing at the moment, than using user 123456789 :)

Answer (score 2):

The only way to check why it fails is using some inspection tool in your browser ie. `FireBug` for `FireFox`. Using this you can check what's wrong with sent requests (or received responses).

Maybe the created path `to Calendar.ics` is wrong... maybe `loadICalSource()` is broken, nobody knows, only you can check it.

Also preview the source HTML of created web-page to check if there is no error in syntax.

**alternative**

Don't want to force you, but you can just clone ready to use FullCallendar sample from github: https://github.com/biesior/Play-20-Sample-FullCalendar-Java.

For working with ajax in Play 2 also it's better to use [javascriptRoutes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11133586/1066240)