# Play Framework CRUD

Tags: rest, playframework, playframework-2.0, crud

I wanted to develop a `RESTful` Application with use of `CRUD` in Play framework. Unfortunately I can't find a way to define `DELETE` and `PUT` in the routes of Play. Maybe there is just `POST` and `GET` available in Play?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure you cannot use DELETE/PUT? The docs say otherwise.

> The HTTP method
>
> The HTTP method can be any of the valid methods
>   supported by HTTP (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD).

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/JavaRouting

Answer (score 5):

Play 2.x has not a CRUD module known from 1.x branch (IMHO fortunately), for defining routes using not standard methods like `DELETE` or `PUT` you need to just use required method in the route:

conf/routes:

```
PUT     /put-item     controllers.Application.putItem()
```

Anyway to use them from the browser methods other than `GET` or `POST` you'll need to create an AJAX call, There is a large [step-by-step](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11133586/1066240) sample on this topic, anyway you can also build it with common [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) by defining the request `type`

```
$.ajax({
  type: "PUT",
  url: "@routes.Application.putItem()",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

A good way to define these is using a wildcard (*) 
This will allow you to use any method valid http method, including those that you have asked about.

For example,

```
*  /items/{id}               Items.display
```

in routes will allow a GET /items/15 or a PUT /items/15.  Use wildcards like this to make your route definitions simpler and more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget OPTIONS method, if you going to use PUT or DELETE from web browser.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did for Delete and Update

```
 POST   /path/:id                 controllers.Controller.update(id: Integer)
 POST   /path/:id/delete          controllers.Controller.delete(id: Integer)
```

And in Controller just

```
 public static Result delete(Integer id) {
    Result result = null;
    if(id>0){
        //your code
    }
    else{
        result = ok("invalid id");
    }
     return result;
}
```

It worked for us for delete and puts

If your intention is only to use RESTFul of play framework and you are using Java it is  better use CXF or Spring webservices or Jersey. Play is a fantastic framework but best fit with play is scala

Answer (score 0):

This is an example router in a play scala application that uses the most prominent http verbs:

```
GET     /                                    controllers.Application.listProjects
PUT     /projects/:name                      controllers.Application.createProject(name: String)
GET     /projects/list                       controllers.Application.listProjects
GET     /projects/:id                        controllers.Application.projects(id: Long)
PUT     /projects/:id/:name                  controllers.Application.addTaskToProject(name: String, id: Long)
PATCH   /tasks/:id                           controllers.Application.modifyTask(id: Long, color:Option[String] ?= None)
```

You can have a look at the whole play scala example project here: https://github.com/nemoo/play-slick3-example