# Play Framework 2.1 Cannot handle JSON POST request from controller

Tags: java, ajax, json, playframework

I am trying to achieve something simple, using play framework 2.1 (java):

Post JSON data via jquery, and retrieve it from a controller.

Could you kindly tell me where I am wrong?

It starts from a javascript call:

```
var object = new Object();

object.title = "Hamlet";
object.author = "Bill";

var jsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object));
jsRoutes.controllers.Application.update().ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    dataType : 'json',
    data : jsonData,
    success : function(data) {
        // I get the success
    },
    error : function(data) {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

The data seems to be correctly posted:
Firebug console:

Headers:

```
Response Headers
Content-Length  2
Content-Type    text/plain; charset=utf-8
Request Headers
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
```

...
Parameters

```
Parametersapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded
title   Hamlet
author  Bill
Source
title=Hamlet&Author=Bill
```

It routes here:

```
POST    /update       controllers.Application.update()
```

Here is the Application Controller:

```
@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
public static Result update() {
    JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();

    if(json == null){
        return badRequest("empty json"); // PROBLEM: THE JSON IS ALWAYS NULL
    }
    return ok("{}");
}
```

And the problem I get is I cannot retrieve my parameters from the request.
the request() seems empty if i print it :

```
DefaultRequestBody(None,None,None,None,None,None,true)
```

Do you see where I am wrong? How could I get the JSON right?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Solved: needed `code`contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`code` in js call.

Comment: Answer your question yourself so you can mark it as correct answer in next 2 days

Comment: related question (which is not answered yet): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19941786/playframework-handling-post-reqeust

Comment: and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19939218/angularjs-http-sending-post-request-fails

Answer (score 5):

I had exactly the same issue. Besides the `dataType`, you have to set `contentType` as well, as the original poster suggested:

```
var jsonMsg = JSON.stringify(msg);
jsRoutes.controllers.Application.sendJson().ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    dataType : 'json',
    contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data : jsonMsg
});
```

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19941786/playframework-handling-post-reqeust

Answer (score 0):

This might help you this example shows how to implement ajax with play step by step
[Play 2.x: How to make an AJAX request with a common button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133059/play-2-x-how-to-make-an-ajax-request-with-a-common-button)