# Playframework handling post request

Tags: json, playframework

In my `routes`:

```
POST        /forms/FormValidator1/validateForm                       controllers.FormValidator1.validateForm(jsonForm:String)
```

There is a controller method defined for that route:

```
def validateForm(jsonForm:String) = Action { ...
```

Then I try to send POST request by chrome POSTMAN plugin (see pic above).

I use:

> **url:** `http://localhost:9000/forms/FormValidator1/validateForm`
>   **headers:** Content Type: application/json
>   **json data:** {name: "me", surname: "my"}

So, sending this POST request I can not reach controller's method by mentioned route / url. **Why?**

**UPDATE:**

Interestly enough: after I got it working on my laptop (see my answer below) then push it on gitHub and pull it to another machine it starts working differently. Now it complains than **Bad Request** is [Invalid XML] nevertheless I use `"application/json"` header and did not change any line of code after commit. I wonder maybe it is a **bug**.

[image]

Comment: There's not a lot to go on here; can you show us the 400 Bad Request response in its entirety? There's often a clue there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems I got it.

Here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/XH3ulCys_co

And here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework/M97vBcvvL58/216pTqm22HcJ

There is `wrong` and `correct` way explained:

```
Doesn't work: curl -d "name=sam" http://localhost:9000/test
Works: curl -d "" http://localhost:9000/test?name=sam
```

This is the way how POST params are passing..in play. (second link is explanation WHY):

> Sometimes you have to make compromises. In Play 1 you could bind your 
>   action parameters from any parameter extracted from the URL path, 
>   query string or even the request body. It was highly productive but 
>   you had no way to control the way the form was uploaded. I mean, if a 
>   user uploads a big file you needed to load the entire request in 
>   memory to be able to handle it.
>
> In Play 2 you can control the request body submission. You can reject 
>   it early if something is wrong with the user, you can process big 
>   files or streams without filling your memory with more than one HTTP 
>   chunk… You gain a high control of what happens and it can help you to 
>   scale you service. But, the other side of the coin is that when a 
>   request is routed, Play 2 only uses the request header to make its 
>   decision: the request body is not available yet, hence the inability 
>   to directly bind an action parameter from a parameter extracted from 
>   the request body.

**UPDATE:**
 Interestly enough: after I got it working on my laptop then push it on gitHub and pull it to another machine it starts working differently. Now it complains than **Bad Request** is **[Invalid XML]** nevertheless I use `"application/json"` header and did not change any line of code after commit.

**UPDATE 2**

So I fixed it like this:

On angular side (we even can comment `dataType` and `headers`):

```
  var data =  $scope.fields

            $http({
                url: '/forms/FormValidator1/validateForm',
                method: "POST",
                //dataType: "json",
                data: data,
                //headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log("good")
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log("something wrong")
            });
```

**On playFramework side: (use [BodyParser](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaBodyParsers))**

```
 def validateForm = Action { request =>


    val body: AnyContent = request.body
    val jsonBody: Option[JsValue] = body.asJson

      // Expecting text body
      jsonBody.map { jsValue =>

            val name = (jsValue \ "name")
            val surname = (jsValue \ "surname")
    ....
    }
```

**Routes (don't define parameters at all !):**

```
 POST       /forms/FormValidator1/validateForm             controllers.FormValidator1.validateForm
```

Comment: also related to my AngularJS question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19939218/angularjs-http-sending-post-request-fails