# Play Framework - Using Javascript Variable in Scala Template

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1

So I have something that looks like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button.fadeMeOut").click(function(){
      var fadeID = $(this).attr('id');
      window.location.href = '@routes.Application.function(fadeID)';
  });
});
</script>
```

Of course this code will give a `not found: value fadeID` error. Is there a way for me to do something like this in Play Scala template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can insert the relative URL in place of '@routes.Application....etc'

So for example 
    `"/function/" + fadeID`

If the route of @routes.Application.function is /function

Comment: Even though I found a workaround to do what I needed in the original post, this solution is very close to my workaround. Accepted as the answer as this way works too.

Answer (score 6):

You can not mix Scala variables (server-side) with JS variables (client-side) as they are generated in quite distant environments.

Instead you can use for an example Play's `javascriptRoutes` like described in [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11133586/1066240)

Comment: Also have a look at the documentation: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaJavascriptRouting