# Reference Scala template code in a separate Javascript File in Play Framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2

If I have something like this in `Application.scala.html`

```
<div id="action">Some content</div>

<script>
    $('action').click(function(){
         window.open(@routes.Application.index());
    )};
</script>
```

This works fine, no problem.

But if I put the script in its own Javascript file, I can no longer use the `@routes.Application.index()` reference. Is is possible in Play to reference Scala templates in a separate Javascript file place under `public/javascripts`?

Comment: [Play Framework - Using Javascript Variable in Scala Template](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17817560/651140)

Comment: Play used twirl. Check twirl documentation: [twirl](https://github.com/playframework/twirl/blob/master/README.md). There is: `Template files must be named {name}.scala.{ext} where ext can be html, js, xml, or txt.`

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered something like this?

```
<div id="action" data-target="@routes.Application.index()">Some content</div>

<script>
    $('action').click(function(){
         var target = $(this).data('target');
         window.open(target);
    )};
</script>
```

You can then extract the JavaScript to its own file.

Although in this particular case an `<a>` tag would be more appropriate (for a number of reasons, including accessibility).