# Jquery and play framework 2 javascript router issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, playframework-2.0

I am new to Javascript and trying to implement AJAX generation of html `DELETE` request to Play 2 Framework server. In Scala template I have this for now. It prints all fields of my model class `Item` and then I need to handle a click at `a href` using JQuery.

**How can I fix the code and also pass appropriate `item.id` into AJAX request?**

```
@(item: Item)

<ul>
  @for(field <- item.getClass().getFields()) {
    <li>@field.getName() = @field.get(item)</li>
  }
</ul>

<a href="#" data-id="@item.id" id="delete">delete</a>



   <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#delete").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        alert(id);
        jsRoutes.controllers.Items.delete(id).ajax({});
        return false;
    });
   </script>
```

This link is very useful but does not give example of integrating jquery and javascript router in detail:

[Play 2.x: How to make an AJAX request with a common button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133059/play-2-x-how-to-make-an-ajax-request-with-a-common-button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the id as an attribute on the delete link:

```
<a href="#" data-id="@item.id">delete</a>
```

And then read that with jquery in your js, something like:

```
$('delete').click( function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    jsRoutes.controllers.Application.Items.delete(id).ajax({
    ...
```

Comment: I have updated the code. alert works if comment out jsRoutes part, but does not if presents.