# Play 2: get reply from server to AJAX

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, playframework-2.0

I have been using AJAX with Play 2 framework to send a request and apply something at server side.

[Play 2.x: How to make an AJAX request with a common button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133059/play-2-x-how-to-make-an-ajax-request-with-a-common-button)

[Jquery and play framework 2 javascript router issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19227835/jquery-and-play-framework-2-javascript-router-issue)

But now I want to make request to server, check something in database and get reply back to AJAX and redraw image or change text.

**What steps should I take to approach it?**

Now I have:

controller

```
public static Result delete(Long id) {
    //...
    return ok();
}
```

view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#delete").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        alert(id);
        jsRoutes.controllers.Items.delete(id).ajax({});
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to send Json response back to browser have a look at official [docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaJsonRequests),
second you have to handle response in javascript like this

```
jsRoutes.controllers.Items.delete(id).ajax({
  success: function(datafromserver) {
   // if success put your logic here        
 },
 error:function(xhr, status, error) {
    // handle exception
 }
});
```