# Play: Performing ajax calls.....?

Tags: ajax, scala, playframework

I can't seem to figure out how to perform ajax calls in Play. I've used other frameworks before and it was just a matter of placing something like `remote="true"` on the form.

How do you use ajax in Playframework? What am I doing something wrong here?

---

Code:

```
/**
 * AJAX Form
 */

@helper.form(action = routes.SomeCtrl.ajaxForm()) {
    <p>
        <input type="submit">
    </p>
}

/**
 * myview.scala.js
 */
@(implicit r: RequestHeader)

$(function() {
    alert("AJAX is working!");
})

/**
 * SomeCtrl ajaxForm def
 */
def ajaxForm() = Action { implicit request =>
    Ok(views.js.myfolder.myview()).as("text/javascript")
    // just testing it
}

/**
 * routes
 */
POST    /assets/javascripts/ajax-form.js controllers.SomeCtrl.ajaxForm()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want include the js the you have to

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="@routes.SomeCtrl.ajaxForm()"></script>
```

according to your code your js will act as a page, and the content written on your js will shown on web as it is written.
for ajax refrence you can check http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJavascriptRouting

and check this question [Play 2.x: How to make an AJAX request with a common button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133059/play-2-x-how-to-make-an-ajax-request-with-a-common-button)

Comment: Note: `javascriptRoutes` in the other question are nice, but not required, @Jon can just use common AJAX call from the jQuery directly to `/assets/javascripts/ajax-form.js` url