# Dynamic content without reloading the page in java using ajax

Tags: ajax

How can we display dynamic content of particular panel of page , without refreshing the page in java using ajax.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get data from server without refreshing the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23966378/how-to-get-data-from-server-without-refreshing-the-page)

Comment: You probably mean Javascript, not Java. If so, please update the question.