# How to use AngularJs Inside the Scala template?

Tags: angularjs, scala, playframework

I'm trying to show the image from the database. However, I can't put the angular variable inside the `@` sign of the Scala template.

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" ng-repeat="product in products">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img class="img-responsive" ng-src="@routes.BookStore.getImage(product.name)">
            ...
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

It gave `Error: Can't find the product variable`. I also tried:

```
 <img class="img-responsive" ng-src="@routes.BookStore.getImage( {{ product.name }} )">
```

It still gave me the same error. How can I use the `AngularJs` variable inside the Scala template?

Answer (score 0):

You **CAN NOT** that's obvious - Scala template is processed at backend side much, much earlier then it arrives to frontend. Instead your Angular app should have some method which will create a string containing path to the image literally, something like `/book-store/get-image/foo.jpg` and then add a route to your *routes* file:

```
GET /book-store/get-image/:fileName   controllers.BookStore.getImage(fileName)
```

Optionally you can try to go with [javascriptRoutes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11133586/1066240), but it's not necessary.

Comment: I did the same thing as you mentioned. I have the route as same as your answer and I also have the `product.name` contained `foo.jpg`. So, how can I call my route by passing the file name variable?

Comment: As I started my answer _You CAN NOT_ use URL's generated by Angular instead